# Generate unique Long Id on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I've three possible ways user can sign in into our service:

- login and password
- Google+
- Facebook

I want to keep all those user id's in one entity. To avoid id collisions between e.g. Google and Facebook a prefix will be added to id (`g-` and `f-` respectively). Currently for users with standard login, an unique `Long` value is generated by App Engine (using Objectify `@Id Long` value set to `null` as id).

To keep everything in one entity the key must be the same type which should be `String`. There's no option in Objectify to auto generate key for `String`.

What I need is to generate unique `Long` value for given entity which will be prefixed with `c-` (custom login). That'd give `String` id similar to those of Google and Facebook. I've searched Objectify's code but found nothing related to generate unique `Long` id for `null` `Long` fields annotated with `@Id`.

Comment: if it's different domains, why should it matter if they have id collision? if it's same domain - you'll get uniq id, and just put user type in some field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a value that is equivalent to the autogenerated id, call:

```
factory().allocateId(Thing.class).getId();
```

Alternatively, you can use the `allocateIds` method on the underlying `DatastoreService` of the low level API. Or even `UUID.randomUUID()`.

However, this sounds weird. Generally you want to be able to map from a Facebook id or Google id to your Human object. Personally I do this with a lookup entity - `FacebookId` or `GoogleId` whose String id is the exact id handed out by FB or G. This should not be a synthetic key, otherwise how would you look it up?

Comment: I have custom Authenticators for login + pass and Facebook auth types. Client side implementations pass the auth token to the backend using header. One with Authorization: Custom [token] header and the other one with Authorization: Facebook [token]. I have also TokenRecord entity which maps token to ClientRecord (which extends User class). In case the token is invalid I'm using the Id to distinguish users and update their token. For Google auth I'm using slightly modified GoogleOAuth2Authenticator which maps Google id directly to the ClientRecord. Do you think this approach is also correct?

Comment: I didn't quite follow but recording authorization tokens (as opposed to ids) in the datastore is strange. From Google I pass the openidconnect id_token to the server and decode/verify it there, which gives me a legit userid. Facebook has some equivalent I am sure.

Comment: I have custom login and pass authentication. When one authorized, user is given generated token and refresh token. I need to keep these tokens somewhere and be able to map every token to user (and check it validity). Of course for Facebook I can use their API to validate the token but I'd like to cache it. It allows me to reduce amount of calls to Facebook API. Do you think is it correct design or should I use another approach? Maybe some auth framework?

Comment: Could you please read my previous comment? In short I have to keep generated tokens in datastore because I'm the one who issued the tokens and have to check their validity.

Comment: You need to keep the refresh token if you want long-term access to the third-party content. Short-term access is a more complicated issue. Maybe you want to create a new stackoverflow question?